# Unable to restore pg_dump backup

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, psql, pg-dump

I'm trying to restore backup from Postgres 9.1.1, which was created by:

```
pg_dump mydb > backup.sql
```

restore on Postgres 9.1.9

```
psql -d mydb -f backup.sql
```

I'm getting this error:

```
psql:datasets.sql:278537: invalid command \.
psql:datasets.sql:278544: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1: 1 4446 49 253.412262 239.618317 0 211.54303 100.482948 197.1...
```

The `\.` is part of `COPY` command, I guess it should be compatible between Postgres 9 versions, or it's not?

```
COPY data_136 (id, in_1, in_2, in_3, in_4, out_1) FROM stdin;
1       5.0999999       3.5     1.39999998      0.200000003     Iris-setosa
2       4.9000001       3       1.39999998      0.200000003     Iris-setosa
--- few more line cutted
150     5.9000001       3       5.0999999       1.79999995      Iris-virginica
\.
```

Comment: I think you meant `psql -d mydb -f backup.sql` or `psql -d mydb < backup.sql`. `-f` is preferable because it lets psql give proper line numbers.

Comment: Yeah, sure. There was `-f` missing.

Comment: You'll probably need to show the line with the `COPY` on it (from the dump), a few lines after and a few lines around the error line.

Comment: I've updated the question. If I'll export it to plain SQL, could it solve the problem?

Comment: I guess the problem might be with unescaped lines containing white spaces, like this one: `chevrolet chevelle malibu`

Comment: The posted COPY data looks fine. Could something have mangled the dump, say converting tabs to spaces?

Comment: Maybe a mess up with the line endings? Did you copy it somewhere with FTP, and it was in ASCII mode (why modern FTP clients even implement that feature, let alone enable it by default, escapes me...)?

Comment: The dump part you provided (`1       5.0999999       3.5 ...`) is different from pert in error message (`1 4446 49 ...`). Can you find the line from the error message?

Comment: I managed to solve the issue, thanks anyway. There were too many errors while importing the dump. The error was caused by the fact that the table didn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by earlier error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for schema pg_catalog
```

I was importing the under user who has all privileges to databases, anyway running the import under `postgres` user solved the issue.

Comment: this is just a hack, but does not solve the underlying issue

Comment: searching for a good one I found this : http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/21919.1396634529@sss.pgh.pa.us

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred to me for the same reason: I was logged in as a user with insufficient permissions.

Just for completeness I'll mention how you can do the restoring whilst specifying the user performing the action:

`psql -U postgres -d mydb -f backup.sql`