# pg_dump from 9.1.7 to 9.1.11

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I would like to import a table from another postgress database (9.1.7) to mine which is (9.1.11). I tried to import the dump but I get a bunch of syntax errors, I'm assuming there is some issue with the version mismatch?

Is there a better solution other than downgrading my postgress installation to match the desired input file?

This is the command I used to export the database on the 9.1.7 system:

```
pg_dump superdb -U tester -a -t guidedata > /tmp/guidedata.sql
```

This is the command I used to import the dump file guidedata.sql

```
psql linuxdb -U tester -h localhost < guidedata.sql
```

This is the top portion of the database dump file which I am attempting to import:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

--
-- Data for Name: epg; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: spy
--

COPY epg (id, channel, sdate, stime, duration, stitle, ltitle, theme, sdesc, ldesc, mpaa, rating, stereo, surround, sap, closedcaptioned, animated, blackwhite, rerun, live, ismovie, nudity, language, violence, adulttheme, halfstars, field1) FROM stdin;
90056520        AMC     01092014        0100    270     Titanic Titanic 8,15    A woman falls for an artist aboard the ill-fated ship.  Leonardo DiCaprio, Kate Winslet (1997) A society girl abandons her haughty fiance for a penniless artist on the ill-fated ship's maiden voyage. (3:15)  MPAAPG13        TVPG    f       f       f       t       f       f       t       f       t       t       t       t       t       8       f
90056521        AMC     01092014        0530    180     Love Actually   Love Actually   23,15   Various people deal with relationships in London.       Hugh Grant, Laura Linney (2003) A prime minister, an office worker, a pop star, a jilted writer, married couples and various others deal with relationships in London. (2:15)   MPAAR   TVPG    f       f       t       t       f       f       t       f       t       t       t       f       t       6       f
90056522        AMC     01092014        0830    150     Four    Four Weddings and a Funeral     23,15   An English charmer meets a lusty American.      Hugh Grant, Andie MacDowell (1994) An English charmer and a lusty American make love over a course of surprising events. (1:56) MPAAR   TV14    f       f       t       t       f       f       t       f       t       f       t       f       t       7       f
90056523        AMC     01092014        1100    30      Paid Prog.      Paid Programming        0       Paid programming.       Paid programming.                       f       f       f       f       f       f       t       f       f       f       f       f       f       0       f
90056524        AMC     01092014        1130    30      Williams        Montel Williams 19      Living well with Montel and the effects of identity theft.      Living well with Montel and the devastating effects of identity theft.                  f       f       f       f       f       f       t       f       f       f       f       f       f       0       f
90056525        AMC     01092014        1200    30      Cindy Crawford  Cindy Crawford Reveals Secret to Ageless Beauty 19      Cindy Crawford's skin secret with Meaningful Beauty.    Cindy Crawford's supermodel secret to youthful, radiant-looking skin with Meaningful Beauty.                    f       f       f       f       f       f       t       f       f       f       f       f       f       0       f
90056526        AMC     01092014        1230    30      More Sex        More Sex, Less Stress   19      Androzene promotes male sexual health & nourishes the body.     Androzene promotes male sexual health and nourishes the body.                   f       f       f       f       f       f       t       f       f       f       f       f       f       0       f
90056527        AMC     01092014        1300    30      WEN Hair Care   WEN by Chaz Dean Revolutionary Hair Care System 19      WEN by Chaz Dean is revolutionary hair care.    WEN by Chaz Dean is revolutionary hair care that cleans and conditions without many shampoo's harsh detergents or sulfates. Natural ingredients help make hair shinier, fuller, softer and more manageable! By trusted GuthyRenker.                     f       f       f       f       f       f       t       f       f       f       f       f       f       0       f
90056528        AMC     01092014        1330    30      Medicare        Looking for a Medicare plan? Tune in now!       19      Watch and learn about Humana Medicare Advantage plans.  Watch and learn about Humana Medicare Advantage plans.                  f       f       f       f       f       f       t       f       f       f       f       f       f       0       f
90056529        AMC     01092014        1400    5       Stooges The Three Stooges       6       The caveman boys meet cavewomen.        Moe Howard, Larry Fine ''I'm a Monkey's Unc
```

Here is some of the error output I see on the console when attempting to import:

```
  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Route"
LINE 1: Route 66 renovation gives Ron a change of heart.  TVPG t f f...
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Ron"
LINE 1: Ron and Jason bring out the Pontiac GTO.  TVPG t f f t f f t...
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "repairing"
LINE 1: repairing the clutch and drive shaft on the 1995 BMW.  TVPG ...
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "classic"
LINE 1: classic Bucik;
```

Thanks

Comment: That's probably not a dump. Could you post the first lines? And how did you generate the dump and how do you import it?

Comment: Hey thanks, I just added the commands I used for import/export and the header of the  import file, if anything else would be useful let me know and I'll add it

Comment: @Hoofamon Any chance you copied & pasted the dump using some tool that might've converted tabs into spaces or otherwise mangled the dump?

Comment: The commands look ok to me, but I see no relation with the error messages. Are you sure that it's the same `guidedata.sql` file? What happen if you pass the first lines? `head -n 14 | psql linuxdb -U tester -h localhost ` ?

Comment: Check also the very first lines of your console error mesages (you can redirect them to a file). And check that your permissions are ok, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440308/unable-to-restore-pg-dump-backup

Comment: Got it working, thanks everyone! @leonbloy, good call, errors on the top of the output clearly informed me that my table was never created due to some missing constraints. All good now!

Comment: Ok. I suggest you write down your solution as an aswer and accept it, so that it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

My guess - one system is linux/unix/mac and the other is Windows.

It's complaining about the first line of the block of data because there is a stray carriage-return (\r) character.

Solution: use the (recommended unless you have a good reason not to) "custom" format with `-Fc` or `--format=custom` on your dump command. That should sort it.